# Does the set of ALL recursive relations exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The photo below was taken from textbook *A Course in Mathematical Analysis* by Prof D. J. H. Garling.

The excerpt is about the proof of Recursion Theorem. In this proof, the author mentions **the set of all recursive relations**.

I would like to ask: How do we know (or prove) that the set of ***all*** recursive relations exist?
[image]

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Why is this a problem? The author starts with a set $A$. If he were talking about the "set" of all recursive relationships he might run into a "set of all sets" logical problem, but I don't see that here.

Comment: But the author clearly wrote "the set S of all recursive relations". Can you elaborate more!

Comment: Sorry - I can't elaborate more without knowing more than I know and spending more time than I have on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm going to assume the author uses the [ZFC axioms for set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) here. It's also quite possible that they're working in "naive set theory," in which case "basic" constructions like the set of all relations with a certain property on a family of sets are simply assumed.*

Well, it's even better: the set $\mathcal{R}$ of all relations (on a given family $X_1, ..., X_n$ of sets) exists. We can prove this by first showing that the Cartesian product $X_1\times ...\times X_n$ exists, and then applying the Powerset axiom.

Then the set of *recursive* relations can be proved to exist by applying Separation to $\mathcal{R}$, using the definition of "recursive relation." *(Note that I'm ignoring what exactly "recursive" means here; the point is that the set of [adjective] relations on a tuple of sets always exists, so long as [adjective] is definable in the language of set theory.)*

Comment: The key observation of course is that this is not the set of "all recursive relations", but rather "all recursive relations *on a given set $X$*".

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila, you correctly help me out of this confusion! Many thanks ^^

Comment: @leanhdung: Indeed, that's why I left that comment.